# Prevent command prompt from closing after the code run

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

I have Microsoft Visual Studio and after I write a code and debug it the command prompt closes directly after the code run. Then I used

```
getc(stdin)
getch()
```

But all these also closes it after a click, Is there anyway to unable it from closing untill I click X?

Comment: `But all these also closes it after a click`, what do you mean, where do you click?

Comment: after a key click like
"Press any key to continue..."

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to keep the output window open after run is finished, though it's pretty similar to what you did(adds a "Press any key to continue . . .")

If you want just to hold the window just add at the end

```
Sleep(100000000);
```

It will hold the window for this many mili seconds.

If it's still not enough do

```
while(1)
{
  Sleep(100000000);
}
```

It will hold the window indefinitely